# Need help getting the SQL strings/query right

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a snippet of code which most likely clears what I want to achieve, but is written badly, especially the final string/query. Basically I make links based on these strings/query.

```
$theanimeid = $row1['anime_id'];
$theanimetype = SELECT * FROM animelist WHERE id=".$theanimeid.";
$echothetype = if $theanimetype['type']=1 echo Movie else echo Episode;
```

The link:

```
$link="Stream-".$title."-".$echothetype."-".$row1['episodes_id']."-".$row1['language']."-".$row1['id'];
```

Some clearing up: $row1 is getting data from the table 'videos', but the column 'type' is inside 'categories' therefore first we need to match the anime_id, a column with the same value as the column id of categories to locate the correct data (I think).

After that we need to get the value for column 'type' in that same row, which is either 0 or 1.

If you need extra information I will reply on the spot, as I refresh this page every minute to see if someone answered, I really need help and it is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Inder

Comment: Pardon me, what is the question?

Comment: Aside from the question being unclear, we might need to see your actual code, as I assume you wrote this as pseudocode.

Comment: @shadyyx The question is, how do I write the strings/queries correctly? Because I know the way I wrote the first 3 strings, is likely deadwrong.

Comment: @Ttony21 It is indeed pseudocode, because I tried to actually keep it as short as possible, the real code would be unbelievably long with many irrelevant information.

Comment: @all What I want to achieve is that instead of .$echothetype. in the link, it either shows Episode or Movie. This depends on whether the value of column 'type' in table 'animelist' is 0 or 1. 

The link is actually based on data from the table 'gallery' as all items e.g. $row1 are retrieving data from columns in table 'gallery'.

Comment: @all The pseudocode is for reference only, no other code has been written relevantly, not even mysql_query/fetch/etc.. I need help with that all :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You mean something like that:

```
$thetype = $theanimetype['type'] == 1 ? 'Movie' : 'Episode';
```

???

Or maybe doing this in the SQL query:

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE type
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Movie'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Episode'
    END AS animeType
FROM myTable
```

Comment: This is indeed better, but I had it figured out, thanks for the input though!!! It is appreciated.